# scope for attribute in belong_to object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, scope, scoping

i have a model CompanyBranch belonging to Company:

```
class CompanyBranch < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  ...
end
```

And Company has an attribute "category_id". Now I want to scope CompanyBranch by its company's category_id. Something like this:

```
scope :category, -> (category_id) { where company.category_id: category_id }
```

But that's not working. What would be the right way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

```
class CompanyBranch < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :company
    scope :by_category, -> (cat) { joins(:companies).where(companies: {category: cat}) }
    # ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to join it also with the categories table, something like following:

```
  scope :category, lambda { | category_id | joins("INNER JOIN categories on company_branches.category_id = categories.id").where("company.category_id: category_id)", category_id) }
```